# Proof of Jordan-Schoenflies via conformal mappings.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, plane-curves, conformal-geometry

The wikipedia article on Jordan-Schoenflies outlines a proof using the Caratheodory theorem on conformal mappings. My doubt is that the proof uses the Riemann mapping theorem. However we do not apriori know the interior of a Jordan curve is simply connected. I checked Pommerenke's book too. But the confusion persists. Some references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just use Jordan curve theorem to get the interior being simply connected?  Or are you trying to prove Jordan curve theorem by Jordan-Schoenflies?

Comment: I don't see how.

Comment: Even if we assume the Jordan Curve Theorem how do we get the interior is simply connected from it? Could you elaborate?

Comment: From JCT, there is an alternative characterisation of simply-connectedness in $\mathbb{C}$: an open subset $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is simply-connected iff for every Jordan curve in $\Omega$ the interior is contained in $\Omega$.  Then it follows immediately that interior of a Jordan curve must be simply-connected.

Comment: @user10354138 may I ask for a reference for the proof that this alternative characterization is equivalent to the standard notion? You say "From JCT", so preferably there is a proof of this only using JCT and general topology (maybe I'll allow complex analysis), not algebraic topology or Jordan-Schoenflies itself.

Comment: It depends on how much Algebraic Topology you know. It is a general fact that the complement to a connected compact subset of $S^2$ has only simply connected components.

Comment: @D.R. If you are willing to use the definition of simply-connected domains that books such as Ahlfors or Markushevich uses: *a domain $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is simply-connected iff its complement in the Riemann sphere is connected* then the proof is indeed immediate from JCT.  Of course the problem is shifted to proving that is equivalent to all loops are null-homotopic (homotopy etc. are arguably "algebraic topology" that you disallow so I won't go into).

Comment: @user10354138 unfortunately the definition of simply-connected I'm thinking of is precisely the null-homotopic version. But I'm wondering if there is a non algebraic-topology proof of the aforementioned facts, in the way that JCT has a non algebraic-topology proof (even though both JCT and Jordan-Schoenflies are better thought of as algebraic topology problems)